# Is there a simple way to curve grades on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, normal-distribution

I have Ranked grades

```
SELECT   Name, Grade,
         @rank_count := @rank_count + (Grade < @prev_value) rank,
         @prev_value := Grade avg
FROM     GradeTable, (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 1) init
ORDER BY avg DESC
```

I have pretty low averages

```
Alex  6.44
Carl  6.33
Greg  6.21
Tom   6.06
```

I want to simply turn the highest grade into a 10 an so on

```
Alex  10
Carl  9.89
Greg  9.77
Tom   9.62
```

I dont want normal distribution complex stuff, can I do a simple curve upgrade, or do  I have to put complex normal distribution formulas to ge the curved numbers?

Answer (score 3):

The ranking appears to have nothing to do with this question.  You can scale the numbers by just getting the maximum and doing some arithmetic:

```
SELECT   Name, Grade, 10 * Grade / maxgrade as scaledGrade,
         @rank_count := @rank_count + (10 * Grade / maxgrade  < @prev_value) as rank,
         @prev_value := 10 * Grade / maxgrade  as avg
FROM     GradeTable CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 1) init CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(Grade) as maxgrade FROM GradeTable) gt
ORDER BY avg DESC;
```

EDIT:

Based on the sample data, it seems that you don't want to scale the grades, just to increase them:

```
SELECT   Name, Grade, (Grade + 10 - maxgrade) as scaledGrade,
         @rank_count := @rank_count + ((Grade + 10 - maxgrade) < @prev_value) as rank,
         @prev_value := (Grade + 10 - maxgrade) as avg
FROM     GradeTable CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 1) init CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(Grade) as maxgrade FROM GradeTable) gt
ORDER BY avg DESC;
```

Comment: I think op wants `grade + (10-maxgrade)` i.e. for Carl 6.33 + (10-6.44) = 9.89

Comment: Btw I personally prefer the 1st formula, glad you kept it in the answer

Comment: I runned it and the values are the same as before the scaledGrade column is the same as the old avg average column

Comment: @Carl . . . Just repeat the expression if you want it as the "avg".  As I say in the first sentence, the ranking has nothing to do with the scaling.  I didn't realize you were using the `avg` column.